# working with class as function parameter in Scala

Tags: scala

Let's say I have the following function:

```
def sampleFunc (c : Class[]) : Boolean
```

It takes a class as parameter. It then checks if a certain element el is of type Class[].
I tried accomplishing that by doing

```
el.isInstanceOf[Class[]]
```

But that doesn't work, it always returns false.
Does someone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

```scala
c.isInstance(el)
```

is the dynamic equivalent of the `instanceof` operator in Java (i.e. the `isInstanceOf` method in Scala).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a type class `scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]`

```scala
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect.classTag

def sampleFunc[T: ClassTag](el: Any): Boolean = {
  classTag[T].runtimeClass.isInstance(el)
}
```

or via pattern matching

```scala
def sampleFunc[T: ClassTag](el: Any): Boolean = {
  el match {
    case _: T => true
    case _    => false
  }
}
```

However, `el.isInstance[T]` is still not supported because of type erasure in java.

Now

```scala
println(sampleFunc[String](""))
println(sampleFunc[String](1))
```

will print `true` and `false` respectively.

Comment: Thank you. When I call the function with my own class, it says: No Manifest available

Comment: @HeloKitay try classTag instead

Comment: That works. Thank you. But why did that actually work?